# How can I generate a square wave plot of a pulse train of multiple signals from the data in a csv file (in Linux)?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, gnuplot

For instance, given the data in a text file:

```
10:37:18.459 1     
10:37:18.659 0     
10:37:19.559 1
```

How could this be displayed as an image that looked like a square wave that correctly represented the high time and low time?  I am trying both gnuplot and scipy.  The result should ultimately include more than one sensor, and all plots would have to be displayed above one another so as to show a time delta.

The code in the following link creates a square wave from the formulas listed,
[link to waveforms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.square.html).  How can the lower waveform (pwm) be driven by the numbers above if they were in a file (to show a high state for 200 ms, then a low state for 100 ms, and finally a high state)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please explain what the data is representing? So what does 10:37:18.469 1 exactly stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I ended up with was:

```
    file_info = os.stat( self.__outfile)
    if file_info.st_size:
        x,y,z,a = np.genfromtxt( self.__outfile, delimiter=',',unpack=True )
        fig = plt.figure(self.__outfile)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        fig.canvas.draw()

        test_array = [(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(e2).strftime('%d_%H:%M:%S.%f')).rstrip('0') for e2 in x]
        plt.xticks(x, test_array)
        l1, = plt.plot(x,y, drawstyle='steps-post')
        l2, = plt.plot(x,a-2, drawstyle='steps-post')
        l3, = plt.plot(x,z-4, drawstyle='steps-post')

        ax.grid()
        ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        ax.set_ylabel('HIGH/LOW')
        ax.set_ylim((-6.5,1.5))
        ax.set_title('Sensor Sequence')
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
        ax.legend([l1,l2, l3],['sprinkler','lights', 'alarm'], loc='lower left')
        plt.show()
```

I had a input file that had convertDateToFloat values in it.  That was passed in to this function.  The name is perhaps misleading (__outfile), but on the previous function, it was the output.

Comment: My source file looked something like: 1577937845.307,0,0,0

1577965463.534,1,0,0
1577965463.735,1,1,0
1577965463.737,1,1,0
1577965463.835,1,1,1
1577965463.835,1,0,1
1577965465.134,1,1,1

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to plot a step function based on timedata. To avoid further guessing please specify in more detail.
In gnuplot there is the plotting style `with steps`. Check `help steps`.

**Code:**

```
### display waveform as steps
reset sesion

$Data <<EOD
10:37:18.459 1
10:37:18.659 0
10:37:19.559 1 
10:37:19.789 0 
10:37:20.123 1 
10:37:20.456 0 
10:37:20.789 1 
EOD

set yrange [-0.05:1.2]
myTimeFmt = "%H:%M:%S"       # input time format
set format x "%M:%.1S" time  # output time format on x axis

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w steps lc rgb "red" lw 2 ti "my square wave"

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this one.  I'll have to give it try.  I've also copied what I ended up with using matplotlib.